# Cisco BGP RTBH in EVPN fabric

Tags: cisco, routing, network, bgp, ddos

I have Cisco basic EVPN fabric configuration in DC with two spine and couple of leafs using OSFP+iBGP for underlay fabric. My border leaf connected to my ISP using Vrf CUST. I want to configure RTBH for DDoS protection. I have RTBH community from my ISP but somehow its not working may be its Vrf issue.

My border-leaf using Cisco 93180YC-EX running nxos 9.3.10 version.

```
route-map RTBH permit 10
  match tag 666
  set community 1299:666
```

In BGP configuration I have set redistribute static for RTBH

```
router bgp 65001
  router-id 10.254.1.2
  log-neighbor-changes
  template peer VXLAN_SPINE
    remote-as 65001
    update-source loopback0
    address-family ipv4 unicast
    address-family l2vpn evpn
      send-community
      send-community extended
  neighbor 10.254.0.1
    inherit peer VXLAN_SPINE
    description ** iBGP Peer to Spine-1 **
    no shutdown
  neighbor 10.254.0.2
    inherit peer VXLAN_SPINE
    description ** iBGP Peer to Spine-2 **
    no shutdown
  vrf CUST1
    log-neighbor-changes
    address-family ipv4 unicast
      redistribute static route-map RTBH
      aggregate-address 81.231.91.0/23 summary-only
    neighbor 213.XX.XX.4
      remote-as 1299
      local-as 31028
      description *** eBGP link to ISP ***
      address-family ipv4 unicast
        send-community
        send-community extended
```

Now if I add static route to test null route using tag 666 it doesn't do anything. Feels like my static route isn't getting install in vrf CUST1. example like following.

```
ip route 81.231.91.128 255.255.255.255 Null0 tag 666
```

I don't have command like `ip route vrf CUST ...blah..` to install route in `CUST1` In that case how do I test my BGP RTBH working or not?

As you can see I don't have option `vrf` in route command.

```
(config)# ip route ?
  A.B.C.D      IP prefix in format i.i.i.i
  A.B.C.D/LEN  IP prefix and network mask length in format x.x.x.x/m
```

## Edit - 1

```
vrf context CUST1
  description ** VRF-CUST1 **
  vni 10555
  rd auto
  address-family ipv4 unicast
    route-target both auto
    route-target both auto evpn
```

Answer (score 0):

`ip route vrf ...` is the IOS syntax. NX-OS does things a bit [different](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/6-x/unicast/configuration/guide/l3_cli_nxos/l3_virtual.html). The routes live under `vrf context ...`

Comment: I have edit my question. as per your comment, I have added route in `vrf context cust1` but it didn't trigger BGP null route. Do you think I should add under `address-family ipv4 unicast` ?

Comment: In routing table I have noticed that /32 route isn't advertise in neighbor peer. Do you think because of router summarization? my all EVPN routes are /32 and that is why I am using summary to send aggregated route to ISP.

Comment: I am reading this doc and its saying you have to configure BGP null route community on remote VTEP also not just border leaf. Am i reading it correct? https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/dcn/nx-os/nexus9000/104x/configuration/vxlan/cisco-nexus-9000-series-nx-os-vxlan-configuration-guide-release-104x/m-configuring-vxlan-bgp-evpn-blackhole.html#concept_cky_r1d_jvb

Comment: Correct. As long as the prefix is covered by a "summary-only" aggregate, only the aggregate will be announced. As it doesn't match the rule, the null route tag will not be added.

Comment: that is what I am thinking that how does null route will show up in table if I am using summary-only. I have check with my ISP and they also can't see any null route coming toward them. If I remove summary-only then it will blast 500 (/32) IPs in ISP table.  Does summary-only and null route doesn't go together?

Comment: If I remove summary-only and that inject /32 null route then Its not overriding existing route in table. that is very odd.. how do I override existing /32 host route using null route and advertise with blackhole community?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When you put a static route in your tables, dynamic routing WILL NOT replace it. The point of adding the route is to announce it to a peer with tag(s) telling _them_ to null route it.

Comment: Hi Ricky, I have post my same question to Cisco and here is the detail thread - https://community.cisco.com/t5/routing/bgp-null-route-in-cisco-evpn-vxlan-fabric/td-p/5046794

Comment: Look like my issue is MAC Mobility community and not sure what is the solution. Just trying to understand how to make it wok.